# Create PushRow in existing section and pass value in runtime

Tags: swift, alamofire, eureka-forms

How to create PushRow dynamically and pass value from alamofire function. This is my alamofire function and i want to create pushRow with the alamofire response

```
nw.getJsonData(api: Api.assetCategory) { (response, error) in

}

func createPushRow(_ title: String, _ placeholder: String, _ options: [String]) {
    form +++ Section("Choose " + title)
        <<< PushRow<String>() { row in
            row.title = title.lowercased()
            row.selectorTitle = "Pick " + title.lowercased()
            row.options = options
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either just change the options of the `PushRow` like this:

```
(form.rowBy(tag: "<tagOfRow>") as? PushRow<String>)?.options = ["", "", ""]
```

Or you can set the `optionsProvider` in the row initializer to `lazy` and get the options each time the PushRow is selected.

```
form +++ Section("Choose " + title)
    <<< PushRow<String>() { row in
            row.optionsProvider = .lazy({ (formViewController, completion) in
                // Call Alamofire to get options
                // options = ...
                completion(options)
            })
            // .... other set up
        }
```